# Unable to locate buttons in protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

There are 3 buttons in an angular application with the following details:

```
<button ng-class="btnClass1" class="btn btn-lg tab" ng-click="addCust()">
<b ng-show="btnClass1 === 'btn-primary'" id="notch" class="notch ng-hide"></b>
"Add Customer" </button>


<button ng-class="btnClass2" class="btn btn-lg tab" ng-click="addCust()">
    <b ng-show="btnClass1 === 'btn-primary'" id="notch" class="notch ng-hide"></b>
    "Open Account" </button>

<button ng-class="btnClass3" class="btn btn-lg tab" ng-click="addCust()">
    <b ng-show="btnClass1 === 'btn-primary'" id="notch" class="notch ng-hide"></b>
    "Customer" </button>
```

I tried following to locate:
var addCustomerButton = element(by.className('btn btn-lg tab'));

But this will only work for the first one as the class name is same for all. Any way to have unique locators for all the three buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `element.all` (https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) which will return an array of the elements so you can access the element by its index in the array (e.g `addCustomerButton[0]`)

Or you can utilize `nth-child()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to specify three different locators for three buttons and just interact with any of these.

However, I don't suggest any of this approaches since this can mess everything up hardly if more buttons gonna be added. Especially if the new button will be added between, let's say button 1 and button 2. Then your button 2 will become button 3, button 3 will become button 4, and so on...

Your to-go option should be to have unique locators for each button